# How do I setup CSRF token for purely REST API communication between two Django applications?

Tags: django, post, http-status-code-403, django-csrf

I have two separate backends both built with Django that I want to communicate with each other. Requests to the `GET` endpoints worked fine but `POST` requests gave me the following error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /endpoint/path/
```

And the instructions from Django mention setting `{% csrf_token %}` in "any template that uses a POST form". But I have no templates! It's just an API.

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "solution" is to just remove the `"django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"` middleware from your `settings.py` but that is not recommended.

There is actually another way to pass the csrf token to your API response without the need for a POST form. The Django docs just do not have an example for this for some reason. It is simply by calling `django.middleware.csrf.get_token()`. Here's an example.

##### Server 1 - Requiring csrf token ("Server")

```
# In a views.py
from django import http
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
...
@http.require_safe
@cache.never_cache
def get_csrf(request):
    # This call will automatically add the token to the response!
    get_token(request)
    return http.HttpResponse("hello world")


@http.require_POST
@cache.never_cache
def post_data(request):
    msg = "received POST request"
    return http.HttpResponse(msg)
```

##### Server 2 - Making requests ("Client")

```
# Also in a views.py
import requests
...
URL = "https://url.to.server/"

def update_session(session, response):
    response.raise_for_status()
    session.cookies.update(response.cookies)
    session.headers["x-csrftoken"] = response.cookies["csrftoken"]

@http.require_GET
@cache.never_cache
def test_api(request):
    # You will want to create a session and store the cookie so it can be easily reused
    session = requests.Session()
    csrf_response = session.get(f"{URL}get_csrf/")
    update_session(session, csrf_response)
    # The previously problematic POST request should now work
    response = session.post(f"{URL}post_data/")

    # `response.text` should now successfully contain "received POST request" 
    return http.HttpResponse(response.text)
```